# C++ HTTP Winsock: "Banned URL" at school, even websites that are permitted

Tags: c++, sockets, http, winsock

I'm fairly new to working with sockets and am working on one of my first projects; the first of which I actually fully intend to complete without any libraries.  I'm on Windows 7, using only WinAPI.

I'm working on it partially at school,and at my school they have a web filter, FortiGuard I believe.  Even when I try to GET a page at a domain that's allowed when I try to open it via a web browser, for example google.com, I'm returned the following message:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<style type="text/css">html,body{height:100%;padding:0;margin:0;}.oc{display:table;width:100%;height:100%;}.ic{display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;height:100%;}div.msg{display:block;border:1px solid#30c;padding:0;width:500px;font-family:helvetica,sans-serif;margin:10px auto;}h1{font-weight:bold;color:#fff;font-size:14px;margin:0;padding:2px;text-align:center;background: #30c;}p{font-size:12px;margin:15px auto;width:75%;font-family:helvetica,sans-serif;text-align:left;}</style>
<title>The URL you requested has been blocked</title>
</head>
<body><div class="oc"><div class="ic"><div class="msg"><h1>The URL you requested has been blocked</h1><p>The page you have requested has been blocked, because the URL is banned.<br /><br />URL = invalid<br /></p></div></div></div></body>
</html>
```

(I tried to break that up a bit).

As you can see it says the URL is banned, and I think that this is the web filter as this only happens when I'm at school

At least I believe I'm using a correct standard HTTP GET request to a website that works normally on a web browser, yet I'm receiving this message.  Am I doing anything wrong with the socket request?

Here's my socket code:

I have a basic "socket_t" structure to pass to all of my functions.  Here's the definition for that:

```
//custom socket structure
typedef struct
{
    //windows-specific
    struct sockaddr win_addr;
    u_long mode;
    SOCKET socket;//acutal SOCKET structure

    // General
    bool listening;//set to true if actively listening
    bool thread_terminate;//when boolean is set to true, listening thread terminates
    void (*error_callback) (int);
    http_response_t * response;
} socket_t;
```

for the connection:

```
//see socket_t definition in socket.h
//returns 0 on success, SOCKET_ERROR on WinSock failure, positive error code on DNS failure
int socket_connect(socket_t * sock, char * addr, int port)
{
    //bear in mind sock is the custom socket_t structure.  sock->socket is the actual SOCKET structure.
    //pardon the nomenclature.  rookie code.
    //TODO:  IPv6 support?

    //DNS lookup structures
    struct addrinfo *   res             = NULL;// Result of the getaddrinfo() call
    struct sockaddr *   sockaddr_v4     = NULL;// IPv4 sockaddr structure

    // So-called "hints" structure detailed in the getaddrinfo() MSDN page.
    // I guess it contains information for the DNS lookup.
    struct addrinfo hints;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family     = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype   = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol   = IPPROTO_TCP;

    //Perform DNS lookup
    DWORD getaddrinfo_res = getaddrinfo(addr, "80\0", &hints, &res);//hardcode port number, for now
    if(getaddrinfo_res != 0) return getaddrinfo_res;

    //for each
    for(struct addrinfo * ptr = res; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next)
    {
        switch(ptr->ai_family)
        {
        case AF_INET:
            sockaddr_v4 = (struct sockaddr *) ptr->ai_addr;//set current address
            sock->win_addr = * sockaddr_v4;//set socket address
        }
    }

    //initialize actual SOCKET
    sock->socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);// TCP/IP, stream-oriented, and TCP rather than UDP; respectively
    if(sock->socket == INVALID_SOCKET) return SOCKET_ERROR;

    //actual connection
    int connect_res = connect(sock->socket, &(sock->win_addr), sizeof(sock->win_addr));
    if(connect_res == SOCKET_ERROR) return SOCKET_ERROR;
    return 0;
}
```

And the HTTP request bit:

```
// Execute an HTTP request.
// Param 1: socket_t object
// Param 2: resource locator not including site name.
int socket_httprequest(socket_t * sock, char * rl)
{
    std::string str_req = std::string("GET /");
                str_req.append(rl);
                str_req.append(" HTTP/1.0\r\n");

                /*
                //user agent header
                str_req.append("User-Agent: conley-client/");
                str_req.append(VERSION);
                str_req.append("\r\n");
                */

                //final newline
                str_req.append("\r\n");

    const char * z_req = str_req.c_str();
    return send(sock->socket, z_req, (int) strlen(z_req), 0);
}
```

They are all called in the main function like so:

```
// Initialization
conley::init_sockets();
conley::init_http();

conley::socket_t * sock = conley::socket_alloc(err_callback);
int connect_res = conley::socket_connect(sock, "google.com\0", 80);
if(connect_res > 0) std::cout << "DNS ERR " << connect_res << std::endl;
if(connect_res < 0) std::cout << "CONNECT ERR " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
if(connect_res == 0) std::cout << "Connected" << std::endl;

int httpreq_res = conley::socket_httprequest(sock, "\0");
if(httpreq_res != -1) std::cout << "HTTP request success: " << httpreq_res << " bytes sent" << std::endl;
else std::cout << "HTTP request failure: Error " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;

conley::socket_listen(sock);
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Why all those `"\0"`? IIRC they are not needed (v.g. `"www.google.com"` is already a `0` finished string). Anyway I do not think this is the bit causing your issues. One option is to use an sniffer like `Wireshark` to check what are you really sending (and comparing to what a browser sends).

Comment: @SJuan76 yeah, good point about the nulls.  And thanks, i'll certainly look into that!

Comment: The error page states `URL = invalid`. Have you tried including a `Host` header in your request, containing, for example, `www.google.com`?

Comment: @Jake: Just keep in mind that `Host` header is only required for HTTP 1.1 requests, but you are sending an HTTP 1.0 request instead. If FortiGuard is requiring that header even for HTTP 1.0 then it is forcing non-standard behavior on clients.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I wasn't even aware of its requirement on HTTP 1.1, but that's great to note, thank you.

Comment: @Jake: Yup, per [RFC 2616 Section 14.23](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-14.23): "A client MUST include a Host header field in all HTTP/1.1 request messages. If the requested URI does not include an Internet host name for the service being requested, then the Host header field MUST be given with an empty value... All Internet-based HTTP/1.1 servers MUST respond with a 400 (Bad Request) status code to any HTTP/1.1 request message which lacks a Host header field."

Answer (score 1):

Probably the error is not caused by your program, but because the filter detects that the request is not send by a browser. Browsers send headers like user-agent to identify themselves to the server that they sent the request to. My  advise is to use a tool like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to capture the traffic generated by a browser and try to mimic it from you application.